# React bootstrap nav-bar styling

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how can I apply styling to a react bootstraps NavBar.
Added jsfiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/pdqzju1e/1/
Having some issue in running the jsfiddle with react-bootstrap. Works on my locally set up environment.

```
const navbar = {backgroundColor: '#F16E10'};
export default class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar style={navbar}>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="/">Test App</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav style={navbar}>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link1</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link2</NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link3</NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The above only seems to work for Nav component and not NavBar. 
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Could you edit your post to add a JsFiddle? It would make debugging much easier.

Comment: @JeremyD Added jsfiddle link. Although having some issue getting it to run with bootstrap. https://jsfiddle.net/pdqzju1e/1/

Answer (score 5):

The problem for me was that background-image was being set to a linear-gradient in one of bootstraps stylesheets. background-image was taking precedence over background-color. Overriding that using the following worked for me:

```
/* override bootstrap navbar colors */
.navbar,
.navbar-default {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#2c4053 0,#2c4053 100%) !important; /* override background image gradient w/ flat color */
}
```

I believe this should have also worked, but it did not for me.

```
.navbar,
.navbar-default {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Im sure there is a much better way of accomplishing this however...

Answer (score 2):

Hey Akshay you can target the `navbar-header` class to override its css attributes. [Here's a jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/zamozigaho/1/edit?css,js,console,output).

```
.navbar-header {
  background-color: #F16E10;
}
```

If that did the trick for you then I'd recommend playing around with Chrome's devtools: inspecting elements and changing their styles to see which css classes you'd want to target.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Navbar
        fixedTop
        style={{backgroundSize: "0", backgroundColor: "#A92117"}}
      >
```

The above is the trick I used in my project. It changes the color to red.

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary links to your own content, as they can be seen as spam by the community. Only include links that are directly relevant to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of MenuItem or NavItem here

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color: white;
    }
```

Basic trick is going to dev-tool and check the css properties and you can do anything.